# A Tournament to Remember

Tags: liars, logic-grid

*The King:*
Recently we had a big tournament, worth being immortalized in the chronicles of my kingdom. Unfortunately, the court scribe misplaced the record of the final event, and we need to restore it. Three knights advanced to the finals: sir Alynore, sir Boras and sir Curtis. In the finals, each of them fought each other once, for a total of three duels. Go talk to them, and reconstruct the events of the finals.

*Sir Alynore:*

(1.1) In the first duel I defeated the knight in red armor.

(1.2) In the second duel the knight on piebald horse lost to the knight in black armor.

(1.3) In the third duel I defeated sir Boras.

*Sir Boras:*

(2.1) In the first duel the knight in red armor has beaten the knight on chestnut horse.

(2.2) In the second duel I was beaten by sir Alynore.

(2.3) In the third duel I have beaten the knight in black armor.

*Sir Curtis:*

(3.1) In the first duel the knight in red armor fought the knight on palomino horse.

(3.2) In the second duel I won against sir Boras.

(3.3) In the third duel I won against the knight in gold armor.

*Puzzled, you return to the King, who says:*

I see you've already met my knights? Alas, none of them is fully reliable in his reports. One of them is a liar, and his stories always have something that is not true. Another we call sir Boast-a-Lot: he always claims that he has won all his duels, but other than that, he’s accurate. The accounts of the third one are always true, with one exception: he is new to the court, and he can never get any names right. Does that help you to sort out the story?

*Reconstruct the finals: the colors of each knight's horse and armor, the participants and the winner of each duel, and which knight can be trusted to what extent.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alynore is

> New, and doesn't remember everyone's name, wearing gold armor, riding a palomino horse, fought in rounds 1 and 3, and won both times.

Boras is

> A lying liar-face, and fought in rounds 1 and 2.  He is wearing red armor, and riding a pie-bald horse, and has not a victory to his name.

Curtis is

> Our resident braggart, and fought in rounds 2 and 3.  He is wearing black armor, riding a chestnut horse, and has one win and one loss.

Logic:

> To start off, we see that B and C give conflicting statements about match one's horses (Red armor vs chestnut/palomino), so one of them must be our liar.  We can then assume that A is not the liar, and anything he says that is not his own claim of victory or a name is true.

Alynore says:
In the first duel I defeated the knight in red armor.

> We know that A was in round one, and not wearing red.

In the second duel the knight on piebald horse lost to the knight in black armor.

> Piebald loses to black.

In the third duel I defeated sir Boras.

> A dueled in this round.

Conclusions so far:

> A does not wear red armor, did not duel in the second round, and therefore cannot be the knight in black armor, so he must be in gold armor.

Now we have to determine

> If Boras or Curtis is the liar.

If we look at Boras' statements:

In the first duel the knight in red armor has beaten the knight on chestnut horse.

> This contradicts A's expression of victory, but okay so far.

In the second duel I was beaten by sir Alynore.

> This could be a lie or a name error.  We know A wasn't in round 2.

In the third duel I have beaten the knight in black armor.

> This introduces some issues.  It implies that C is in black, and was in rounds 2 and 3, when we know that Alynore was in in round three.  Boras is our liar.

Sir Curtis

> Isn't our liar, so let's see if he's the braggart, or just new here.

In the first duel the knight in red armor fought the knight on palomino horse.

> Checks out.

In the second duel I won against sir Boras.

> Entirely possible, but Lyin' Boras says that he beat A.  Let's ignore him.

In the third duel I won against the knight in gold armor.

> Contrast with A's claim that he defeated Boras in round 3

Conclusions:

> A doesn't remember names, B is our liar, and C is our braggart.  A fought in rounds 1 and 3, B fought in rounds 1 and 2, and C fought in rounds 2 and 3.  A is riding a palomino horse, wearing gold armor, and 2-0 in his matches.  Boris is wearing red armor, so Curtis is wearing black.  Curtis (black) defeated piebald in round 2, so Boris has a piebald horse, and Curtis has our chestnut horse.